# Solve for inverse transform sampling

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

**Given**

- Random variable $Y$ has probability density $\rho(y)$
- $\rho(y) \propto (s - y)^{n}$
- $s \in [1, \infty)$
- $y \in [0, 1]$
- $n$ is a positive integer

**Goal**

Find function $f$ such that

- $Y = f(U(0, 1))$
- $U(0, 1)$ is the unit uniform random variable
- When $x$ is drawn from $U(0, 1)$, $0 \le x \ \le 1$

**Attempt**

$$1 = \int_{0}^{1} (s-y)^{n} dy = \left [ -\frac{(s - y)^{n + 1}} {n + 1} \right]_{0}^{1} = \frac{s^{n+1} - (s - 1)^{n+1}}{n + 1}$$

Therefore,

$$\rho(y) = \frac{(s - y)^{n}(n + 1)}{s^{n+1} - (s - 1)^{n+1}}$$

Let $y = f(x)$. Since $x$ follows $U(0, 1)$, $\rho(x) = 1$. Then,

$$1dx = \rho(x)dx = \rho(y)dy$$

$$x = \int \rho(y)dy = - \frac{(s - y)^{n + 1}}{s^{n+1} - (s - 1)^{n+1}} + C$$

$$f(x) = y = s - [(x - C){s^{n+1} - (s - 1)^{n+1}}]^{1/(n + 1)}$$

Don't know what to do at this point.